# AS3 - change sprite attributes dynamically using loop won't work

Tags: ios, for-loop, sprite, actionscript-3

I'm trying to change attributes of various sprites using loop. However I'm getting this error message and I have no idea how to fix it:
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property transform not found on String and there is no default value.
    at LevelScreen/LevelUnlockedColor()[/Users/jakub/Cloud Drive/Documents/JH_WORK/IMPOSSIBLE_SCREEN/LevelScreen.as:232]
    at LevelScreen()[/Users/jakub/Cloud Drive/Documents/JH_WORK/IMPOSSIBLE_SCREEN/LevelScreen.as:31]
    at Function/MainMenu/LoadMenu/taphandler2Click()[/Users/jakub/Cloud Drive/Documents/JH_WORK/IMPOSSIBLE_SCREEN/MainMenu.as:94]

Here is the code:

```
public function LevelUnlockedColor()
    {
        mySharedObject.data.Unlocked = 3;
        mySharedObject.flush();
        var boxes:Array = [];
        for (var i:int = 0; i<mySharedObject.data.Unlocked; i++)
        {
            var spriteName:Sprite = new Sprite();
            spriteName.name = "LVL" + i;// "sprite_0" "sprite_1" ...

            boxes[i] = spriteName.name;
            boxes.push(spriteName);

            var trans:ColorTransform = boxes[i].transform.colorTransform;
            trans.color = uint(0xd982ab);
            boxes[i].transform.colorTransform = trans;

            trace(boxes[i]); //output LVL0, LVL1, LVL2
        }

    }
```

Thank you.

And here is the rest of the code:

```
package
```

{

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.ui.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.filesystem.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flashx.textLayout.accessibility.TextAccImpl;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.geom.*;


public class LevelScreen extends Sprite
{

    Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
    public var LVL1:Sprite = new Sprite  ;
    public var LVL2:Sprite = new Sprite  ;
    public var LVL3:Sprite = new Sprite  ;
    public var LVL4:Sprite = new Sprite  ;
    public var LVL5:Sprite = new Sprite  ;
    public var LVL6:Sprite = new Sprite  ;

    public var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("LevelsSaved");

    public function LevelScreen()
    {

        DrawLevels();
        LevelUnlockedColor();

        var PauseBtn:MainMenu = new MainMenu();
        PauseBtn.GamePaused();
        addChild(PauseBtn);

        LVL1.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP,taphandler1);
        LVL2.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP,taphandler2);
        LVL2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,taphandler2Click);



        LevelCheck();


    }

    public function DrawLevels()
    {
        LVL1.graphics.beginFill(0xe6e7e8);
        LVL1.graphics.drawRect(50,90,260,260);
        addChild(LVL1);


        LVL2.graphics.beginFill(0xd1d3d4);
        LVL2.graphics.drawRect(330,90,260,260);
        addChild(LVL2);


        LVL3.graphics.beginFill(0xbcbec0);
        LVL3.graphics.drawRect(50,370,260,260);
        addChild(LVL3);


        LVL4.graphics.beginFill(0xa7a9ac);
        LVL4.graphics.drawRect(330,370,260,260);
        addChild(LVL4);


        LVL5.graphics.beginFill(0x939598);
        LVL5.graphics.drawRect(50,650,260,260);
        addChild(LVL5);


        LVL6.graphics.beginFill(0x808285);
        LVL6.graphics.drawRect(330,650,260,260);
        addChild(LVL6);
    }

    public function HideAll()
    {

        removeChild(LVL1);
        removeChild(LVL2);
        removeChild(LVL3);
        removeChild(LVL4);
        removeChild(LVL5);
        removeChild(LVL6);
    }


    public function taphandler1(event:TouchEvent):void
    {

        var LoadLVL1:LEVEL_01 = new LEVEL_01();
        LoadLVL1.drawLVL_01();
        addChild(LoadLVL1);
        HideAll();
    }



    public function taphandler2(event:TouchEvent):void
    {

        if (mySharedObject.data.Unlocked >= 1)
        {

            var LoadLVL2:LEVEL_02 = new LEVEL_02();
            LoadLVL2.LoadLevel2();
            addChild(LoadLVL2);
            HideAll();
        }
        else
        {
            trace("LEVEL 02 is locked");
        }
    }

    public function taphandler2Click(event:MouseEvent):void
    {

        if (mySharedObject.data.Unlocked >= 1)
        {

            var LoadLVL2:LEVEL_02 = new LEVEL_02();
            LoadLVL2.LoadLevel2();
            addChild(LoadLVL2);
            HideAll();
        }
        else
        {
            trace("LEVEL 02 is locked");
        }
    }




    public function LevelCheck()
    {


        if (mySharedObject.data.Unlocked >= 1)
        {

            trace("some levels unlocked already " + mySharedObject.data.Unlocked);

        }
        else
        {
            mySharedObject.data.Unlocked = 0;
            mySharedObject.flush();
            trace("new sharedobject created " + mySharedObject.data.Unlocked);
        }
    }

    public function LevelUnlockedColor()
    {

        mySharedObject.data.Unlocked = 3;
        mySharedObject.flush();
        var boxes:Array = [];
        for (var i:int = 1; i<mySharedObject.data.Unlocked; i++)
        {
            var spriteName:Sprite = new Sprite();
            spriteName.name = "LVL" + i;// LVL0 , LVL1 ...

            boxes[i] = spriteName;
            //boxes.push(spriteName);

            var trans:ColorTransform = boxes[i].transform.colorTransform;
            trans.color = uint(0xd982ab);
            boxes[i].transform.colorTransform = trans;
            addChild(boxes[i]);
            trace(boxes[i].name);//output LVL0, LVL1, LVL2
            trace(trans);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `for` loop like this:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i<mySharedObject.data.Unlocked; i++)
        {
            var spriteName:Sprite = new Sprite();
            spriteName.name = "LVL" + i;// LVL0 , LVL1 ...

            boxes[i] = spriteName;
            //boxes.push(spriteName);

            var trans:ColorTransform = boxes[i].transform.colorTransform;
            trans.color = uint(0xd982ab);
            boxes[i].transform.colorTransform = trans;

            trace(boxes[i].name); //output LVL0, LVL1, LVL2
        }
```

In this way you'll actually make transformations on sprites and not on their names. And if you also need to add these object on stage , put this line before your `trace`:

```
addChild(boxes[i]);
```

**Update after question edit.**
Ok , try to change the `for` loop in the `LevelUnlockedColor` function like this:

```
 for (var i:int = 1; i<mySharedObject.data.Unlocked; i++)
        {
            var lvl:Sprite = this["LVL" + i];

            var trans:ColorTransform = lvl.transform.colorTransform;
            trans.color = uint(0xd982ab);
            lvl.transform.colorTransform = trans;

        }
```

Comment: thank you very much. The code seems to be working fine (no error, yay). However the colour of the sprites won't change. All the sprites are already visible. What I'm trying to do here is to change a color of a tile (new level) when you unlock this particular level. Anything obvious you could think of? If you want I can post the remaining code here as well...

Comment: @cubeec yes , it will be nice if you update your question with updated code

Comment: Done. Just to let you know: I'm not very good at programming so please don't tell me off too much :-) I work as UI/UX designer and this is just my side project... thanks a lot.

Comment: @cubeec your code is ok more or less , but it is need some refactoring of course. i've updated my answer , try it now

Comment: Genius :-) It worked. Thank you very much! What annoys me is fact that the solution is pretty much always soooo easy! But as I said I'm just a designer (http://www.n-ll.com) fed up with the lack of developers that are willing to work on own (unpaid) projects and this is my desperate attempt to be able to do both, design and develop :-)

Comment: @cubeec Great , glad it helps (also you welcome to "accept" this answer)! Good luck with your innovations!